# Vue template fail to render the ajax result

Tags: vue.js, axios, render

I working on a project using vue and axios, according to the console, it looks the axios has response, but don't know why the result cannot render to the html page and any advice to how to debug vue? thanks!
here is the code snippet

```html
<ul id="tasklist" class="list-group">
  <li v-for="task in todo_task_list" :key="task.id">
    {{ task.content }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
<script>
  var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#tasklist',
    data () {
      return {
        todo_task_list: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios
        .get('/todo/api/todotask/')
        .then(function(response){
          this.todo_task_list = response.data
          console.log(todo_task_list)
        })
        .catch(function (error) { 
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  })
</script>
```

here is the result display in the console
[image]

Comment: To debug vue, I recommend using vue dev-tools, if you aren't using it already. Here's a link for installing it with [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en). Also, I advice that you use camelCase instead of snake_case in javaScript as that is the convention. It's also more readable and it prevents errors like `a__variable` instead of `a_variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `function(response)`  this sets the context of `this` to be of that function. So when you later use `this.todo_task_list`, you are still in the context of that function and not of the vue instance. Thus, the `todo_task_list` you declared in `data(){...}` is never changed.

You can use arrow-functions to preserve the parent context of `this`.

So if you want `this.todo_task_list` to point to the vue instance you can do:

```
await axios
  .get('/todo/api/todotask/')
  .then( (response) => {                // <-- arrow-function!
    this.todo_task_list = response.data // Now "this" is the vue-instance.
    console.log(todo_task_list)
  })
  .catch(function (error) { 
    // Here you don't use "this." so it doesn't matter either way.
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: You are right about the context being the issue. However, he `mustn't` use arrow functions to get the Vue instance as the context. There are other techniques such as binding `this` to the function etc. Arrow functions are just the most succinct and modern way to do this.